# Default country code for Firebase Phone Authentication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Have a nice day, guys!

I have a Flutter source code using Firebase for Phone Authentication when users signup/signin. But users have to wrire full phone number with country code. It's annoyed!

**Specific situation:**

My app for Vietnam with country code is +84 only. Length of Vietnamese phone number is 10.

I want +84 to be default country code and users write their standard phone number only (example 0912345678).

So please tell me what files I have to edit in this source code to make default country code before phone number in number field.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is your app that provides a number, so you can implement UI in any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'[+]')),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard looks nicer as `TextInputType.phone` than `TextInputType.number`.

However, you can use inputFormatters to prevent non-digit letters.

```dart
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
)
```